# cURL sending XML to webservice. Need different encoding

Tags: web-services, soap, curl

Is there any way to set cURL to send this XML with `&lt;` and `&lt;` instead of `<` and `>`

```
    $xml_data = '
    <Shipping_Address>
    <Province>BC</Province>
    <Country>Canada</Country>
    <PostalCode>V6P 5T2</PostalCode>
    <Phone>604-561-7977</Phone>
    </Shipping_Address>';

$ch = curl_init($URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml','charset=ISO-8859-1'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($output);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems strange that this would be required, if the webservice is expecting XML. But if it is, you should be able to do it by calling `htmlentities()`:

```
$xml_data = htmlentities('
    <Shipping_Address>
    <Province>BC</Province>
    <Country>Canada</Country>
    <PostalCode>V6P 5T2</PostalCode>
    <Phone>604-561-7977</Phone>
    </Shipping_Address>');
```

Comment: yea i know its strange. i was wondering if there was a specific cURL option for it. ill just do it this way i guess thx.